# How can I implement Sign-In-With-Apple in a webview?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, sign-in-with-apple

I have implemented SIWA natively on iOS, however it is only offered on iOS 13+.  Is there a way to do an iOS 12- fallback SIWA in a webview? I am having trouble finding any examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sign in With Apple** doesn't make the whole app incompatible with `iOS 12` or lower (the same is for SwiftUI).

If you want to support **Sign in With Apple** on older versions of iOS (as well as the **non-iOS** platform) you can use [Sign in with Apple JS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs) framework.

Useful link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119198

Comment: From what I have seen, Sign in with Apple JS has only been used on traditional webpages.  Could this be used in tandem with a native iOS app?

Comment: Sign in with Apple JS is common for all like you can also add this feature for Android. If you want to feel like native then you need to check the iOS version and implement the way you like.

Comment: looks like the popup option does not work in WKWebView: `popup_blocked_by_browser`